# Converting graphics to features in ArcGIS Desktop using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, feature-set

Is there a way to convert a graphic to feature, i.e. use the "Convert Graphics to Feature" tool on the toolbar, within an ArcPy script?

I need to use a graphic as a selectbylayer feature, so either converting it or using the graphic directly would be nice.

Answer (score 7):

There appears to be no SelectLayerByGraphic tool equivalent to SelectLayerByLocation so I think you are correct to seek an alternative approach.

There also appears to be no "ConvertGraphicToFeature" tool.

I looked for whether you could access a graphic drawn in Data View from Python but GRAPHIC_ELEMENTs appear to be available for resizing and repositioning only.

If what you are looking for is a way to feed a "graphic" drawn by the end user into a Python script tool then the alternative you may wish to use is to request the user to draw the "graphic" by using a [Feature Set](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001n000000) as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Select all graphics you want to convert to shape.
On the Drawing toolbar, choose "Convert Graphics to Features". Fill in the appropiate fields in the pop-up window and you're good to go.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange :) and thank you for your contribution. However the OP is asking how to do this from a script, not interactively. In your defence I see that's not clear; I'll update the Q.